# Forcing horizontal scroll in iFrame in IE6 when loaded page is suppressing

Tags: css, iframe, scrollbar

Have a client with a kiosk app that loads a major hotel's site in an iframe in IE6.  The page is wider and longer than the iframe.  Setting `scrolling="yes"`  or `scrolling="auto"` results in scrollbars in all modern browsers but IE6 only shows vertical scrollbars and we are stuck with it on the kiosk.  IE6 does not even show a disabled horizontal scrollbar.

My current attempt has no scrolling or sizes except in this style attribute:

```
    style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll; 
   -ms-overflow-x:scroll; -ms-overflow-y:scroll; width:858px; height:715px"
```

But IE6 is still not showing even a disabled horizontal scrollbar.  Interestingly I can set the width down from 858px  to 100px and never get a horizontal scrollbar.

/*  IMPORTANT UPDATE */
Per Krumelur's suggestion I loaded other pages and found they would scroll so I checked the CSS on the Holiday Inn page we are loading and found `html {overflow-x:hidden\9;}`

So I tried adding `!important`  to my styles but that did no good.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying "horizontalscrolling=yes" on the iframe. If that does not help put the iframe in a div and put the div's overflow to auto. 
My assumption otherwise is that the page you are displaying in the iframe adjusts to the frame's width. Have you tried another page?

Comment: More than one way to skin a bad browser!  Thanks!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: Which one worked? The "horizontalscrolling" or the DIV trick?

Answer (score 1):

try this `scrolling="yes" horizontalscrolling="yes" verticalscrolling="yes"` in your iframe tag

Comment: No change in IE6 behavior.  Thanks for reply!

Comment: try doing what Krumelur suggested, create a div with fixed width and height, set overflow to auto and put the iframe in the div with 100% width and height